# MenuItem attached menu-items turn gray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I have a MenuItem with attached NSMenu to it.
To the NSMenu, items are added with target/action etc.
Everything works great, the software runs perfect, the menu appears with the items, and they are enabled and perform their action.

**But**, 1 to 100 customers, reports that the menu items turns gray (disabled, picture below), and they do not turn enabled, ever again. Even after App-restart and even after reboot.
Even the quit item which sends terminate: to NSApplication, configured using the Interface Builder, shows disabled.

What is happening here?

[image]

Comment: How are you setting up this menu?

Comment: using the Interface builder.

Comment: Do you enable/disable menu items in your code?

Comment: No, I don't...  even the quit item which is so simple, bonded to the terminate: action, goes gray. what can be causing this?